# Syntax error using tags in django template with {{ }}

Tags: python, django, templates, pycharm, tags

Using Pycharm Pro 2020.2 Python 3.8 Django 3.1.2

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def truncate(request):
    name = 'Very long name'
    return render(request, "truncate.html", {'name': name} )
```

**urls.py**

```
re_path(r'^test/$', truncate, name='truncate'),
```

**truncate.html**

```
{{ name }}<br />


{{ name|truncatewords:2 }}<br />


{{ name }}|truncatewords:2<br />
```

**Output**

```
Very long name
Very long …
Very long name|truncatewords:2
```

Problem shows using Pycharm Code Inspect on the .html page.

I get these 2 errors:

```
Expected }}

and


{{ or {% expected
```

an error pointing at the line with: {{ name|truncatewords:2 }} which gives the right output

and

no error at the line with: {{ name }}|truncatewords:2 which gives the wrong output.

Thanks for any help.

Gilles

Comment: For the last case: there is no error, because it is correct `{{ name }}` is correct, and the rest it is just plain text allowed in HTML. Could you check that you set Django template engine (and not Jinjia2, which doesn't use the `:` syntax).

Comment: Yes I had Jinja2 selected as the template language. Solved. Thank you.